# AVR Simulator like Proteus on ubuntu?

Tags: serial-port, simulator, avr, atmega16

I am looking for an IDE not for compiling code, but for simulating a compiled code for AVRs, mainly ATMega16 ...

I am familiar with Proteus on windows but as it turns out, it's not available for ubuntu and i would hate to install wine just for that...

I would be really thankful if any of you knows a simulator similar to Proteus that is available on linux, and preferably open source..

Mainly, i would like to simulate RS232 signals as it's becoming a pain to flash the chip after every small change to check the results...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never tried `simulavr`, but it is packaged on Ubuntu:

```
$ apt-cache show simulavr
Package: simulavr
...
Description: Atmel AVR simulator
 simulavr simulates the Atmel AVR family of micro-controllers,
 emulates a gdb remote target, and displays register and memory
 information in real time.
Homepage: http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/simulavr
```

Other distributions may or may not have it so easily available -- and there might be better choices. Still, hope this helps.

Comment: i was looking for something more advanced, but it will do for now thanks :)